# With QProcess, Is it necessary to call waitForReadyRead after waitForFinished?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qprocess

I use the code below to capture the 'help' from the standard output of a command line utility.  This code has worked without problems until this morning when someone encountered an issue (the message box appeared that stated that the command looks odd).

I can't seem to reproduce the problem, so I'm about to chalk it up to a system anomaly, since the utility is located on a network shared drive and we have systems that are burdened with security processes which cause a lot of lag.

Would it be beneficial to add a `waitForReadyRead` check, or is it redundant?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
QProcess cmd_process;
cmd_process.setWorkingDirectory("x:/working/directory");
cmd_process.start(R"(t:\bin\win\cmdlineutility.exe)", QStringList() << "/help");
if(cmd_process.waitForFinished())
{
    // TODO - should waitForReadyRead() go here?
    QByteArray ba = cmd_process.readAll();
    if(ba.contains("something good"))
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Something wrong", "cmdlineutility looks odd");
    }
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "something wrong", "total fail");
}
```

Comment: Is that the real code?  A single backslash in a string literal starts an escape sequence.  And are you certain the command in question still works as expected at a command line?

Comment: Not the real code.  Unable to copy the real code.  I'll fix it.

Comment: And yes, the command does work, this portion of the code has been working like this for the last few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in `qprocess_win.cpp` both 
[`QProcessPrivate::waitForReadyRead(int msecs)`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qprocess_win.cpp.html#682) and [`QProcessPrivate::waitForFinished(int msecs)`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qprocess_win.cpp.html#778)
perform the same actions:

- calling

  `stdoutChannel.reader && stdoutChannel.reader->waitForReadyRead(0)`
- and when finished, calling

  `drainOutputPipes()`

So when `waitForFinished()` returns, all available data will have been read into the output buffers.

Comment: I notice that `waitForReadyRead` checks the return value of `drainOutputPipes` while `waitForFinished` does not.  I'm using Qt 5.8.0, so maybe it's different in the latest version.  Working my way around the code to see if that makes a difference for my case...

Comment: Confirmed.  The call to `waitForReadyRead` returns false after `waitForFinished`.

Comment: @JimmyG That's because `waitForReadyRead()` needs to tell the caller if there is anything to be read.